# Cython: how to go from numpy memory view to vector[pair[double,double]] without needing the GIL?

Tags: c++, numpy, cython

I am trying to convert all Python calls in my Cython code to pure C to be able to release the GIL and do parallelisation.

I used to work with a list of lists-of-size-2 initialized from a 2D numpy array so I did something like that:

```
cdef double[:,:,:] init=np.random.uniform((10,4,2),dtype=np.float32)

cdef int i
cdef int N=init.shape[0]
for i in range(N):
  a=init[i].tolist()
  #I then get this list of list 
  #a=[[1.,1.],[1.,1.],[1.,1.]]
  #f acting on list of list
  f(a)
```

I need to release the GIL inside the loop so I need to remove all the calls to Python. By using vector[pair[double,double]] instead of lists and modifying f accordingly I now have:

```
cdef vector[pair[double,double]] a 
cdef double[:,:,:] init=np.ones((10,4,2),dtype=np.float32_t)
cdef int i
cdef int N=init.shape[0]
for i in prange(N):
  #I need to get a vector[pair[double,double]] from the numpy init[i]
  #with f now cdef acting on vector[pair[double,double]]
  a=np.asarray(init[i]) #actually works but it goes through Python !
  f(a)
```

How to convert init[i] (thus a double[:,:] type) to a vector[pair[double,double]] without going through python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any solution to go from memoryview or even numpy to `std::vector` without using the GIL. The only solution I found was to first convert the big array to a `vector[vector[pair[double,double]]]` and then you can access it without the GIL in a second for loop where you are doing all the intensive computations.