# Cython convert numpy ndarray (N,4,2) to vector[vector[pair[double,double]]

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have spent litterally weeks changing my cython code to pure C (still in Cython though) to gain speed and to be able to remove the GIL to do multithreading to gain even more speed.

With the help of fellow stackoverflow users I finally succeeded and gained a factor 10 pure C vs cython with some python and then again a factor 3 by using 4 threads (with prange) **in the double for loop** part of my code.

**BUT** in order to enter this loop I first have to convert two 3 dimensional `numpy ndarrays` of dimensions (N,4,2) (and (K,4,2)) to `vector[vector[pair[double,double]]]`. K and N being reasonably large.

For this I am doing:

```
cdef int N=200000 #Of this order of magnitude
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=3] numpy_array=np.random.uniform(size=(N,4,2))
t1=time.time()
cdef vector[vector[pair[double,double]]] c_structure
c_structure.reserve(N)
cdef int i
for i in range(N):
  c_structure.push_back(numpy_array[i])
t2=time.time()
```

Yet this part of code which I deemed trivial has become the new bottleneck of my code !!! The double for loop takes on my computer **0.1s** (instead of 1.11s in the original implementation) single thread and this part takes **3 whole seconds**(1.5s for each array) ! Which makes my super optimized code 3 times slower than my original code (1.5*2+0.1) !

What am I doing wrong ?! How to speed this ?!

See [another related question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799114/cython-how-to-go-from-numpy-memory-view-to-vectorpairdouble-double-without)

Comment: Not really important in this context but `np.random.uniform((N,4,2))` doesn't return a 3D array... Please try to make the [mcve] at least relatively correct.

Comment: Thanks it is now corrected

Comment: Is it possible that most of the time is in generating random numbers?

Comment: No I timed it after the array creation it is just to give an example

Comment: I will improve my question

Comment: Are you bound to using a `vector[[..`?  The most performant solution would be to directly pass the numpy array data pointer into your c code and work on the elements without a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won a factor of 100 in speed by explicitely initializing each element of the vector. Indeed with a cython -a it now has 0 yellow lines.

```
cdef int N=200000 #Of this order of magnitude
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=3] numpy_array=np.random.uniform(size=(N,4,2))
t1=time.time()
cdef vector[vector[pair[double,double]]] c_structure
cdef vector[pair[double,double]] empty_vector, vector
cdef pair[double,double] a1, a2, a3, a4
c_structure.reserve(N)
cdef int i
for i in range(N):
  a1.first=numpy_array[i,0,0]
  a1.second=numpy_array[i,0,1]
  a2.first=numpy_array[i,1,0]
  a2.second=numpy_array[i,1,1]
  a3.first=numpy_array[i,2,0]
  a3.second=numpy_array[i,2,1]
  a4.first=numpy_array[i,3,0]
  a4.second=numpy_array[i,3,1]
  vector.push_back(a1)
  vector.push_back(a2)
  vector.push_back(a3)
  vector.push_back(a4)
  c_structure.push_back(vector)
  vector=empty_vector
t2=time.time()
```

**0.036s instead of 3s**

Comment: Good to see you're on the right track.  `empty_vector` and a1/a2/a3/a4 can be removed if you simply do `vector.resize(4)` once at the top then assign directly into it, e.g. `vector[0].first = numpy_array[i,0,0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! I did not know the .resize() method !

Answer (score 2):

You have an Nx4x2 array and you are converting it to `vector[vector[pair[double,double]]`.  In C++, vectors of vectors are not efficient.  Instead, you should create a 4x2 struct and make a single vector of those.  Or, better yet, you should directly use the NumPy array in C++ as a pointer to Nx4x2 array.  In other words, stop copying your data unnecessarily, but if it is necessary, copy to a fixed Nx4x2 structure instead of NxMx2 which is slow.

Comment: I upvoted the answer but I found a much much better way and won a factor 100 on the initialization.

Comment: I will possibly look into struct later

Comment: I have my reasons for having a variable sized structure inside the vector so I need to have a `fixed_size_vector[variable_sized_vector[(double,double)]` that is why I chose `vector[vector[pair[double,double]]]`

Comment: @jean: OK, but your question specifically said it was Nx4x2 not NxMx2.

Comment: Yes I agree but in fact in my code the two fixed Mx2 vectors give rise to a temporary variable-sized nx2 vector (with n depending on the two vectors). It helps at least readability if the two structures are the same but you are right I could use struct for the parents and vector[vector[]] for the child.